# How to add comments to questions and answers in Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, comments, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

I am trying to add comments to previous questions. But I am not able add comments to those questions. Why am I not able to post questions?

Comment: There should be nothing stopping you from posting questions. What issues are you running into? (You should be able to leave comments here, since this is your own question. Use the "add comment" link.)

Comment: See also: [How do comments work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have amassed enough "reputation" to leave comments.
https://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation

My understanding of the site, is that you have to contribute in order to gain enough points to contribute more. It means that the site has a level of accuracy  and is not full of spam. For example, if you accept answers, and give answers, and ask questions, then you can contribute more.
So, if there are other questions that you have - then one way, for now, may be to post a question on the topic. I'm not certain as to what you are looking for, but you are trying to engage the original person who posted the question - so perhaps try to ask a new question - or indeed post a new answer to the original question - and see does it elicit a response from someone.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But how can i know the issue regarding answer without adding comment

Comment: Just make sure the answer posted is an actual answer to the question and not another question or comment. Otherwise, asking a new question is indeed the correct approach ;)